# Union of finite and non-regular language

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, closure-properties

**Question:** ($B$ and $C$ are languages)
$B$ is finite,$C$ isn't regular:

Prove/Disprove: $C\cup B$ isn't regular.

**Thoughts:**
My intuition says this is true, but I need an idea to prove it. Since I don't know if $C$ as a CFG or RE language I don't know what kind of machine I can build for it.

Comment: We expect you to make a serious effort before asking here.  What methods do you know for proving a language isn't regular?  Have you tried each of them?  Where did you get stuck, specifically?  It looks like you need to make more of an effort on your own -- your textbook will have many worked examples of techniques for proving that specific languages are not regular.  So, spend some time trying each one.  P.S. I recommend you get clearer on the difference between "$C \cup B$ isn't *necessarily* regular" vs "$C \cup B$ is never regular".

Answer (score 5):

Hint 1: Try to prove the contrapositive, namely: if $C\cup B$ is regular and $B$ is finite, then $C$ is regular.

Hint 2: Use closure properties of regular languages.

Comment: Strictly speaking, the contrapositive of "If $B$ is finite and $C$ is not regular, then $C\cup B$ is not regular" is "If $C\cup B$ is regular then $B$ is infinite or $C$ is regular".

Comment: @RickDecker: Unless I first assumed that $B$ is finite and was talking about _if $C$ is not regular, then $C\cup B$ is not regular_.

Comment: I understood that. I was being pedantic, having nothing better to do with my time this afternoon.

Comment: @RickDecker: I'm watching the TV series Fargo. Very enjoyable. Maybe give that a go.